# For loop: writing dictionary iteration output to excel using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate over a dictionary that contains multiple row indexes in its values and then apply pd.nsmallest function to generate the top 3 smallest values for the multiple sets of row indexes that are in the dictionary. However, there seems to be something wrong with my for loop statement as I am overwriting the top 3 values over and over till the last set of values in the dictionary and so my final excel file output shows only 3 rows for the last run of the for loop.

When I use print statements this works as expected and I get an output for all 16 values in the dictionary but when writing to excel file it only gives me the output of the last run on the loop

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
VA = pd.read_excel('Columnar BU P&L.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Variance by Co')

legcon = VA[['Expense', 'Consolidation', 'Exp Category']]
legcon['Variance Type'] = ['Unfavorable' if x < 0 else 'favorable' for x in legcon['Consolidation']]

d = {'Travel & Entertainment': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 'Office supplies & Expenses': [13,14,15,16,17],
'Professional Fees':[19,20,21,22,23], 'Fees & Assessments':[25,26,27], 'IT Expenses':[29],
'Bad Debt Expense':[31],'Miscellaneous expenses': [33,34,35,36,37],'Marketing Expenses':[40,41,42],
'Payroll & Related Expenses': [45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56], 'Total Utilities':[59,60],
'Total Equipment Maint, & Rental Expense': [63,64,65,66,67,68],'Total Mill Expense':[70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77],
'Total Taxes':[80,81],'Total Insurance Expense':[83,84,85],'Incentive Compensation':[88],
'Strategic Initiative':[89]}
```

Printing output directly works fine when I do this:

```
for key,value in d.items():
    a = legcon.iloc[value][legcon.iloc[:,1]<0].nsmallest(3,'Consolidation')
    print(a)

                Expense  Consolidation            Exp Category Variance Type
5  Transportation - AIR         -19054  Travel & Entertainment   Unfavorable
9                 Meals          -9617  Travel & Entertainment   Unfavorable
7               Lodging          -9439  Travel & Entertainment   Unfavorable

            Expense  Consolidation        Exp Category Variance Type
26     Bank Charges          -4320  Fees & Assessments   Unfavorable
27  Finance Charges          -1389  Fees & Assessments   Unfavorable
25     Payroll Fees          -1145  Fees & Assessments   Unfavorable
```

However when I use the below code to write to excel:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('testt.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
row = 0
for key,value in d.items():
    a = legcon.iloc[value][legcon.iloc[:,1]<0].nsmallest(3,'Consolidation')
    for i in range(0,16): 
        a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'test', startrow = row+4, index = False)

writer.save()
```

my output looks like this and does not show all the exp categories:
[image: the output of the last iteration of the loop]

I would really appreciate any feedback on how to correct this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from a friend I just realized my silly mistake, there was no row iterator in my for loop for the output to print on the next lines and using the below code fixed the issue (initially i placed the row iterator within my df.to_excel statement):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('testt.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
row = 0
for key,value in d.items():
    a = legcon.iloc[value][legcon.iloc[:,1]<0].nsmallest(3,'Consolidation')
    a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Testt', startrow = row, index = False)
    row = row+4
writer.save()
```